# Sort 2d numpy array based on one column with float numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array as below. I want to sort the rows based on the values in the last column by using numpy. I still want the objects in the other columns to follow. Tried argsort but it complained about the float values. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
array([[ 1.        ,  9.78451265, 18.31697539, 19.41765432],
       [ 1.        ,  9.49327265, 16.33220702, 17.52747136],
       [ 1.        ,  9.59539133, 19.12802603, 20.06255417],
       [ 1.        , 10.71154356, 20.97159265, 22.20762462],
       [ 1.        ,  9.80546193, 20.42898466, 21.33123542],
       [ 1.        ,  7.15263928, 19.34313597, 19.34749615],
       [ 1.        , 10.04666903, 17.44804702, 18.77179989],
       [ 1.        ,  8.17590068, 21.42497094, 21.64885651],
       [ 1.        ,  9.48726923, 21.25501335, 21.96131382],
       [ 1.        , 10.33621213, 21.96221091, 22.94731233],
       [ 2.        , 30.81113115, 41.62138476, 50.3865105 ],
       [ 2.        , 30.9706931 , 39.05822859, 48.44245254],
       [ 2.        , 31.5019972 , 40.58579837, 49.97406593],
       [ 2.        , 29.715156  , 40.25178835, 48.63397036],
       [ 2.        , 31.72687542, 40.42059829, 49.9812409 ],
       [ 2.        , 27.70096179, 39.21068387, 46.61542365],
       [ 2.        , 35.11019075, 37.99593126, 50.32100995],
       [ 2.        , 30.66515427, 38.941767  , 48.16221612],
       [ 2.        , 32.8454404 , 44.25996075, 53.71737408],
       [ 2.        , 28.68922489, 38.77826805, 46.83898709]])
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you show us how you used argsort? Should be as easy as `y = x[np.argsort(x[:,-1])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any ideas on how to solve this?*

I used `numpy.argsort` without problem as follows:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1.0,1.0,5.3],[1.0,2.0,4.7],[1.0,3.0,3.5]])
sorted_arr = arr[np.argsort(arr[:, -1])]
print(sorted_arr)
```

output

```
[[1.  3.  3.5]
 [1.  2.  4.7]
 [1.  1.  5.3]]
```

In my example `dtype` is `float64`. Please check if `dtype` of your array is actually some float, by doing `print(your_array.dtype)`. Note that [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) has optional argument `kind`, default is *quicksort*, you might give a try different versions and look what will happen.

Comment: used arr.argsort(arr[:,3:]), when using arr[np.argsort(arr[:,3])] it works, than you!

Comment: `arr[:,3:]` results in 2D array (you slice in 2 dimensions), whilst `arr[:,3]` result in 1D array as you slice then get one of columns